# How secured is my registration form?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

I am new in PHP programming and I have a registration form which allows my visitors to register in my website, but I'm not sure about security and how secure my code is.  The code is shown below:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$search   = array("<", ">", "join", "union", "'", "/", "(", ")", "Join","jOin", "joIn", "joiN", "Union", "uNion", "unIon", "uniOn", "unioN");
$replace  = "";
$username = str_ireplace($search, $replace, $_POST['username']);
$email = str_ireplace($search, $replace, $_POST['email']);

if (empty($_POST['username']) or empty($_POST['email']) or empty($_POST['pass']) or empty($_POST['confirmpass'])) {
    echo "<p>Please Fill all filds</p>";
}
elseif ($_POST['pass'] != $_POST['confirmpass']) { 
    echo "<p>Match Password</p>";
}
elseif (strlen($username) > 20){
    echo "<p>Your Username should less than 20 Char</p>";       
}
else{
    $username    = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($username));   
    $email       = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email'])); 
    $pass        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);    
    $pass        = md5($pass);  
    $confirmpass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['confirmpass']); 
    $confirmpass = md5($confirmpass);   
    $date   = date("Y-m-d");

    $checkq = mysql_query("SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username='$username' ");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($checkq);
    if($num_rows >= 1){ 
        echo "<p>you have to choose another Username</p>";
    }else {

    $checkq2 = mysql_query("SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE email='$email' ");
    $num_rows2 = mysql_num_rows($checkq2);  
    if($num_rows2 >= 1){ 
        echo "<p>that email is already registerd <br />".$email."</p>";
        }else {
                        $insertuser = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users 
                        (id, username, password, rdate, email) 
                        VALUES 
                        ('', '$username', '$pass', '$date', '$email')
                        ");         
                        if ($insertuser){ echo "<span>you are login successfuly ...</span><META http-equiv='refresh' content='4;URL=http://www.6arbyat.com/join/login.php'> ;";}else{echo "<p>Sorry there is something Wrong !!!</p>"; 
                        }   
                    }
                }
                }
            }
```

Any comments?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **code review request**. This is better suited to the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Before posting there be sure to read their [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to ensure that your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: If I use a password like, *JointMonkeysUnion123* or something that contains either or both of the words you are trying to filter out, am I left with trimmed password and in return I don't actually know my real password? and a bonus point, your password can even be a SQL query, but once hashed it does not matter to your application. Just make sure to not trust user input :)

Answer (score 4):

```
"Join","jOin", "joIn", "joiN"
```

Not even a tiny bit secure.

Use proper parametrized queries if you care about security, or just paste the values in your queries if you don't. Either way, the bulk of your code is useless.

```
$insertuser = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users 
  (id, username, password, rdate, email)
```

Also, you probably shouldn't write raw passwords in your database, it makes your code look like it was written in 1985.

Comment: You forgot to mention he needs to use `mysqli` instead of the deprecated (hope I spelled that right) `mysql`

Comment: *"Also, you probably shouldn't write raw passwords in your database, it makes your code look like it was written in 1985."*, or Sony's